# Does PostREST have a null-safe not-equal operator, like IS DISTINCT FROM?

Tags: postgresql, sql-null, postgrest

I'm making some simple PostgREST queries on a table with network device properties. It seems that `eq` and `not.eq` both exclude `null` values. I've learned that [that's a “feature” of PostgreSQL](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/03/05/handling-null-values-in-postgresql/), and [can be worked around with the `IS DISTINCT FROM` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36509358/1144854), which treats `null` as a comparable value.

I can't find an equivalent (null-safe not-equals) operator in [PostgREST](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html#operators). Is there one?

Simplified example:

```json
# https://example.com/api?select=*&name=like.spam-*
[{
  "name":"spam-eggs",
  "type":"router",
  "sector":"cheese"
},{
  "name":"spam-ham",
  "type":"router",
  "sector":null
}]
```

`not.eq.cheese` excludes `cheese` and `null`:

```json
# https://example.com/api?select=*&name=like.spam-*&sector=not.eq.cheese
[]
```

My awkward workaround is using `or` to include `null`s:

```json
# https://example.com/api?select=*&name=like.spam-*&or=(sector.not.eq.cheese,sector.is.null)
[{
  "name":"spam-ham",
  "type":"router",
  "sector":null
}]
```

Am I stuck with that workaround, or is there an operator like `isdistinctfrom`, `neq-or-null`, etc. that I've missed?

Comment: @Belayer The question is about [PostgREST operators](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html#operators), OP already knows about `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.

Comment: Correct. PostgREST not.eq PostgreSQL. ;) I have tried, out of desperation, things like `.distinct.`, `.is.distinct.`, `.isdistinctfrom.` and gotten errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Current answer**

Since PostgREST version 11.0.0, the `isdictinct` operator is translated to `IS DISTINCT FROM` in PostgreSQL. Using your example, the new query would be:

```
https://example.com/api?select=*&name=like.spam-*&sector=isdistinct.cheese
```

**Original answer (Oct 2022)**

I've checked the code and there's no implementation of `IS DISTINCT FROM` right now. That is, no PostgREST operator translates to it. The only reference I found is in a comment in [this file](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/blob/cfaeff8a5a76f541fc744ea9b97321ce65dc426e/src/PostgREST/Query/SqlFragment.hs#L265), but it's for a different issue.

So, yes, right now, your workaround would be the closest you can get to the behavior you want. Creating a `FUNCTION` with a custom query using `IS DISTINCT FROM` is another alternative, although it requires more heavy lifting.

Comment: Just created [a new issue](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/2501) referencing this question in the github repo.

Comment: it worked! `isdistinct` added in [#2739](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/pull/2739) and released in either v10.2.0 or v11.0.0 (unclear to me). Thank you! Want to update your answer or should I add a new one?

Comment: @Jacktose Yes, to confirm, it was included in [v11.0.0](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/releases/tag/v11.0.0).